# Create document with images from different folders?

Tags: r, powerpoint

Lets say I carried out an experiment that produces lots of microscope images. I have multiple samples: Sample1, Sample2, etc. and each sample has varying amounts of images and divided into different folders.

I want to create a document which contains all images of each sample arranged neatly (ideally 1 page for every sample) so I can have an overview of my experiment. I usually do this manually on PowerPoint, but now Im producing overwhelming amounts of data and it would take too long. PPT is useful because it compresses my large image files very well, otherwise my images are over 5 GB in total.

The R packages I found that create PPT, however, only allow you to add images that have been produced in R. I could create a PDF document but then i would need to compress the images (either at the end or as i add them).

I know R isn't the ideal language for these kind of things, but its the one I know best and would appreciate any sort of suggestions/packages. Thanks!

Edit: The images are tiff files.

Comment: This should be possible using `officer`. It'd also be possible to resize and reduce the size of your images using `magick`.

Comment: It's not r, but ... I have a free Windows/PPT add-in that might help. When you run it, it lets you choose any number of images from a folder. It inserts the first image onto the current slide then adds a duplicate of the starting slide for each add'l chosen image and inserts that image onto the slide. You'd have to run it once per section but it'd still save quite a bit of time, I suspect.  https://pptools.com/free/FAQ00006-ImageInsert.htm

Comment: Thanks everyone. I think I'll just use reportlabs on python. I will need to learn it at some point anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
library(officer)
library(rvg)
library(png)

doc <- officer::read_pptx()
doc <- officer::add_slide(doc,"Title and Content","Office Theme")
Picture<-readPNG(system.file("img","Rlogo.png",package="png"))
grid::grid.raster(Picture)
ggdml <- dml(grid::grid.raster(Picture))
doc <- officer::ph_with(doc, ggdml, location = officer::ph_location_type(type="body",position_right = FALSE))
print(doc, target = "test.pptx")
```

Comment: to get all images within subfolders you can use files <- list.files(path = ".",pattern = "*.png",recursive = TRUE)